How to make a Gamepad Bluethoot Controller for Android on Sketchware Pro App?
Dear Stack Overflow community,
I am a programming and video game enthusiast, but I am new to the world of development and only have mobile devices to carry out my projects. At the moment, I am looking for help to create a Bluetooth GamePad Controller using Sketchware, a visual programming platform that has been very useful for me to develop mobile applications.
My goal is to create a wireless game controller that connects to my mobile device via Bluetooth, allowing me to play my favorite games with a more comfortable and console-like experience. However, my lack of experience and knowledge in programming has prevented me from making progress in this project.
That is why I turn to you, experts in the field, to guide me and help me overcome the obstacles I have encountered along the way. In particular, I am having trouble using the Bluetooth component of Sketchware, which I consider essential for the correct functioning of my game controller.
I appreciate any advice, suggestion, or help you can provide me, and I am willing to collaborate and share my progress in the project with the community.
Thank you very much and greetings to all!
I tried to use the sendData block in Sketchware to send key events to my mobile device using the Bluetooth component, but unfortunately, it did not work as expected.
bt.SendData(_bt_bluetooth_conection_listener, "sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT));", "A");
To be more specific, I attempted to use the sendKeyEvent function inside the sendData block to send key events that would simulate the input of a game controller. However, despite my efforts, the key events were not being recognized by my mobile device, and I was unable to control the game using my Bluetooth GamePad Controller.
I was expecting the key events to be recognized by my mobile device and for the game to respond accordingly, allowing me to control it using my Bluetooth GamePad Controller. However, what actually resulted was that the key events were not being recognized, and I was unable to control the game.
I am still trying to figure out what went wrong and how to fix it, so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Related: Can an Android device pretend and connect as a Bluetooth controller?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
